# how to reverse number with retaining there signs in c#

Tags: numbers, reverse

i have large negative integers i want to reverse it with their signs example suppose i have -654321 i want output as -123456. 
i have write code which reverse the positive number when i give negative value it gives 0.

my code:

```
int Number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int Reverse = 0;
        while (Number > 0)
        {
            int remainder = Number % 10;
            Reverse = (Reverse * 10) + remainder;
            Number = Number / 10;
        }
  Console.WriteLine("Reverse No. is {0}", Reverse);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

this converts only positive number not negative i also want to retain their signs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int OriginalNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int Number = OriginalNumber;
if(OriginalNumber < 0)
{
  Number = Math.Abs(Number);
}

    int Reverse = 0;
    while (Number > 0)
    {
        int remainder = Number % 10;
        Reverse = (Reverse * 10) + remainder;
        Number = Number / 10;
    }
    if(OriginalNumber < 0)
    {
        Reverse = (Reverse * -1);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Reverse No. is {0}", Reverse);
    Console.ReadLine();
```